# How to start IIS Express in background mode from cmd or PowerShell and VS Code?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, iis, cmd, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code with php-debug extension, IIS Express and PHP (IIS/PHP from Web PI) and trying to automate IIS Express startup with a `preLaunchTask` on `launch.json` file from Visual Studio Code. So I wrote those things below on my `launch.json` and `tasks.json` files.

All things work nicely, except for the fact that VS Code keeps locked on IIS Startup, because IIS stay running, waiting for the user input (i.e.: "Q" to quit IIS). This way, even with IIS running ok, I couldn't debug inside VS Code, because it's waiting the IIS task to finish.

I've tried with Powershell and `Start-Job` (PS script excerpt below) without success, because PowerShell seems to start IIS, but nothing happens (IIS is not started).

How could I accomplish that?
Where I'm doing it wrong?
Thank you in advance.

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000, "preLaunchTask": "start_server"
        }
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json -- cmd version**

```
{
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "command": "cmd.exe",
   "isShellCommand": true,
   "args": [
       "/C",
       "runphp.cmd"
   ],
   "tasks": [
       {
           "taskName": "start_server",
           "isBuildCommand": false,
           "showOutput": "always"
       }
   ]
}
```

**tasks.json -- Powershell version**

```
{
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "command": "PowerShell.exe",
   "isShellCommand": true,
   "args": [
       "-ExecutionPolicy",
       "ByPass",
       "-File",
       ".\\wahoo.ps1" // my powershell script
   ],
   "tasks": [
       {
           "taskName": "start_server",
           "isBuildCommand": false,
           "showOutput": "always"
       }
   ]
}
```

**wahoo.ps1 -- only used when I set the powershell version from tasks.json**

```
$scriptDir = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
$command = @'
cd $scriptDir | cmd.exe /C runphp.cmd
'@

Start-Job -Name "IISPHP" -Arg $command -ScriptBlock {
    param ($command)
    Invoke-Expression -Command:$command
    Start-Sleep 3
}
```

My `runphp.cmd`is an adapted version of the original `runphp.cmd` from IIS/PHP installation folder to suit my needs and contains the following:

**runphp.cmd**

```
SET pf=%ProgramFiles%
if DEFINED ProgramFiles(x86) SET pf=%ProgramFiles(x86)%

set appcmd="%pf%\iis express\appcmd.exe"
set iisexpress="%pf%\iis express\iisexpress.exe"

cd > tmpFile
set /p currentdir= < tmpFile
del tmpFile

where php-cgi.exe > tmpFile
set /p phprt= < tmpFile
del tmpFile
if DEFINED phprt goto setup_iis
SET phprt=%pf%\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe

:setup_iis
%appcmd% set config /section:system.webServer/fastCgi "/+[fullPath='%phprt%']" "/apphostconfig:%currentdir%\applicationhost.config"
%appcmd% set config /section:system.webServer/handlers "/+[name='PHP-FastCGI',path='*.php',modules='FastCgiModule',verb='*', scriptProcessor='%phprt%',resourceType='Either']" "/apphostconfig:%currentdir%\applicationhost.config"
%iisexpress% /site:EmptySite /config:"%currentdir%\applicationhost.config"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (in my case I needed to run a browser from within VS Code) and this is how it worked for me.

At first I created a file only containing one line for passing two commandline-parameters of that file to the command-interpreter.

**my_vsCode_tasks.cmd**

```
%1 %2
```

which says 'run program %1 with argument %2'.

And this was my corresponding

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "C:\\path\\to\\file\\my_vsCode_tasks.cmd",
    "tasks" : [
        {
            "taskName": "Tool 1",
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "args": ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\my\\first\\tool.exe", "${file}"],
        },
        {
            "taskName": "Tools 2",
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "args": ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\my\\second\\tool2.exe", "${file}"],
        },
    ]
}
```

I also tried it alternatively with powershell. Worked too. This was my

**runTool.ps1**

```
$whichTool=$args[0]
$whichArg=$args[1]
start-process "$whichTool" -ArgumentList "$whichArg"
```

With a slightly different

**tasks.json**

```
{
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "command": "call",
   "isShellCommand": true,
   "showOutput": "always",
   "args": ["powershell", "-NoProfile", "-file", "C:\\path\\to\\file\\runTool.ps1"],
   "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "C:\Program Files (x86)\my\second\tool.exe",
            "suppressTaskName": false,
            "args": ["${file}"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you @RobertK I'll check this out!

Answer (score 0):

There's an IISExpress extension made for VS Code: https://github.com/warrenbuckley/IIS-Express-Code

Comment: That extension is useless for PHP projects as it injects a default applicationHost.config file that does not have the necessary configuration settings to enable PHP. The developer has stated that he does not plan to support custom applicationHosts.config files either.